# Multi Touch and Display

Tags: xorg, xinput, touch-screen

I have dual-monitor setup, both are touch screen of different size and of different model.
I get following result when I execute command:

```
 user@user-hpEnvy:~$ xrandr
    Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
    eDP1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
       1920x1080      60.0*+   59.9     40.0  
       1680x1050      60.0     59.9  
       1600x1024      60.2  
       1400x1050      60.0  
       1280x1024      60.0  
       1440x900       59.9  
       1280x960       60.0  
       1360x768       59.8     60.0  
       1152x864       60.0  
       1024x768       60.0  
       800x600        60.3     56.2  
       640x480        59.9  
    HDMI1 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
       1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0     59.9  
       1680x1050      59.9  
       1600x900       60.0  
       1280x1024      60.0  
       1440x900       59.9  
       1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
       1024x768       60.0  
       800x600        60.3  
       720x576        50.0  
       720x480        60.0     59.9  
       640x480        60.0     59.9  
       720x400        70.1  
    VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

And result of next command is as:

```
   user@user-hpEnvy:~$ xinput
    ⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
    ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎜   ↳ Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:401b   id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎜   ↳ Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:4016   id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎜   ↳ ELAN20E7:00 04F3:20E7                     id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
        ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ HP Truevision HD                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ HP WMI hotkeys
```

Here I have two display: **eDP1** and **HDMI1**
Also, having two touch device: **ELAN20E7:00 04F3:20E7** and **SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad**

Now, question is, how do I identify which touch screen belong to which display ?
I want to identify this mapping for further operations.

**OR**

Is it possible to enlist all USB devices connected from Board to Monitor ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the xinput --map-to-output command option.

Try this:

First command maps the touch device "ELAN20E7:00 04F3:20E7" to your left eDP1 monitor.

Second command maps the touchpad "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" to your right HDMI1 monitor

```
xinput --map-to-output $(xinput list --id-only "ELAN20E7:00 04F3:20E7") eDP1
xinput --map-to-output $(xinput list --id-only "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad") HDMI1
```

If you run these you can tell which touch device goes with which screen.